# Geting git repo from windows to mac

Tags: git

Trying simple clone:

```
192-168-0-100:shop nonamez$ git clone "user@76.242.151.105/var/www/html/s1"
fatal: repository 'user@76.242.151.105/var/www/html/s1' does not exist
192-168-0-100:shop nonamez$ git clone "git://user@76.242.151.105/var/www/html/s1"
fatal: could not create work tree dir 's1'.: No such file or directory
```

Only works windows version

```
git.exe clone   --progress -v  "user@76.242.151.105:/var/www/html/s1" "C:\Users\Desktop\Projektai\s11"
```

But it creates filder with name `C:\Users\Desktop\Projektai\s11`

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. What is wrong with the folder name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `user@76.242.151.105/var/www/html/s1`, you probably want `user@76.242.151.105:/var/www/html/s1` or `ssh://user@76.242.151.105/var/www/html/s1`.

These 2 representations I provided are equivalent. Note the colon in the first representation. The first is essentially a shorthand of the second. Both of these use ssh as the underlying protocol. `git://` is a different one which uses a native protocol.

For more details on git url, type `git help clone` or visit [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html), and go to section "GIT URLS".